# Question about Notation. What does this means? $f[0]=1, f[0,1]=-1$

Tags: numerical-methods, notation

Question about Notation. What does this means?

$f[0]=1, f[0,1]=-1, f[0,1,2]=2$ (The values are exact, which is pretty confusing too, if they are refering to intervals)

This question is from a numerical analysis paper about using polynomials to approximate functions.

It goes "Determine the quadratic polynomial that interpolates p(x) at x=0,1,2. Then find a good upper bound for etc...

Thank you.

Comment: Where and in what context did you encounter this notation?

Comment: It's hard to say from this context. I've seen this notation in case of the image of $f$, or as the integer notation, such that $f[0,1]=-1$ would mean that $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=-1$.

Comment: @Yellow Skies : this is very strange notation.  I've never seen it before.  Can you provide a link to the paper or another paper by the same author?

Comment: @YellowSkies: Look at item $(13)$ through $(16)$ at: http://www.math.uh.edu/~jingqiu/math4364/interpolation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way of constructing a polynomial that fits data points:

$$p(x) = f [z_0] + f [z_0,z_1](x-z_0) + f [z_0, z_1, z_2](x-z_0)(x-z_1) + ...$$

where $$f[z_0, z_1, ... z_n] = \frac{(f[z_0, z_1, ... z_{n-1}] - f[z_1, z_1, ... z_n])}{z_0 - z_n}.$$

For your example, you have at least $p(0) = 1$, plus some others for $p(1)$ and $p(2)$.

Immediately you have that $f[0] = p(0) = 1$.  Then you calculate $f[0, 1]$ from $p(0)$ and $p(1)$ (whatever that is).  From there, you can calculate $f[1, 2]$ knowing $p(2)$ whatever that is, and then finally get $f[0, 1, 2]$ from $f[0, 1]$ and $f[1, 2]$.

More [here.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~oleary/c460/polyinterp4.pdf)